# IntelliJ IDEA's "External Libraries" shows every class shows twice after adding dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

How it looks in External Libraries:

[image: SCREENSHOT: How it looks in External Libraries]

Does anyone know why that's happening, and does that have any problematic side effects?
This happens when adding the dependency with JitPack or by pulling it from GitHub packages.

Tried adding the following to the dependency `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
  implementation.resolutionStrategy {
    preferLatestVersion()
    }
}
```

It crashes with the following error:

```
Could not find method preferLatestVersion() for arguments [] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolutionstrategy.DefaultResolutionStrategy.
```

Comment: Are your dependencies correct when you run a dependency report? (gradle dependencies)

Comment: @GreenSaguaro Thanks for your response. I didn't check the dependencies, but see my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the both class and source files were included in the JAR. I added the following at the end of `build.gradle` and now only class files are included:

```
jar {
     // Exclude source files from the JAR
     exclude('**/*.java')
}
```